# Reboot & continue batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Below is the script created for increasing the swaps & mounting the driver. Now in this script I want to add the feature that after setting the page file the system will be rebooted & once reboot is done, it will resume with next step which is mounting driver. Can you please help in this.

```
@echo off

wmic pagefileset create name="D:\pagefile.sys"

wmic pagefileset where name="D:\\pagefile.sys" set InitialSize=20480,MaximumSize=25480

echo "Pagefile created.
```

---

Need to add script to reboot the windows & after reboot continue with next step

---

```
DISKPART /s C:\Users\Desktop\param_files\instructions.txt
echo "Drive mounted successfully"
```

Regards

Comment: You may be interested in a [RunOnce Registry Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Alternatively, you can add the 2nd part of batch as a start-up program, run it, and than finally remove the script. By the way, try `shutdown /r` - it reboots the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mark where you want to restart your script like:

```
@echo off

REM Initialization here

if "%~1" neq "" goto :%~1

REM Do some stuff1 here
call :markReboot stuff2

REM Making sure to not execute some part of stuff2 before rebooting
goto :eof 

:stuff2
REM Do some stuff2 here
call :markReboot stuff3
goto :eof

REM ...

:stuffn
REM Do some stuffn here
goto :eof

:markReboot
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /t REG_SZ /d "\"%~dpf0\" %~1" /v  RestartMyScript /f 
shutdown /r /t 0
```

**NOTE:** The `/f` is not really needed in the `reg add` command.

**EDIT:** Adapting my answer to your specific should look like:

```
@echo off

if "%~1" neq "" goto :%~1

wmic pagefileset create name="D:\pagefile.sys"
wmic pagefileset where name="D:\\pagefile.sys" set InitialSize=20480,MaximumSize=25480
echo "Pagefile created. 

call :markReboot stuff2
goto :eof

:stuff2
DISKPART /s C:\Users\Desktop\param_files\instructions.txt
echo "Drive mounted successfully"
goto :eof

:markReboot
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /t REG_SZ /d "\"%~dpf0\" %~1" /v  RestartMyScript /f 
shutdown /r /t 0
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am new in scripting. The code you have written above is this a complete code for scripting or do I just need to add reg add command (reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /t REG_SZ /d "\"%~dpf0\" %~1" /v  RestartMyScript /f ) in my script.

Comment: @hans Yes, adding `reg add` to your code will guarantee that your script is executed next time you logon. This is also some kind of general template, you have to replace the sections **Do some stuff here** with your actual needs.

Comment: Just to confirm  if I understand it correct.
can you please validate below code

@echo off

wmic pagefileset create name="D:\pagefile.sys"

wmic pagefileset where name="D:\\pagefile.sys" set InitialSize=20480,MaximumSize=25480

echo "Pagefile created"

reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /t REG_SZ /d "\"%~dpf0\" %~1" /v  RestartMyScript /f 
shutdown /r /t 0

DISKPART /s C:\Users\Desktop\param_files\instructions.txt
echo "Drive mounted successfully"

Comment: I tried it but it is kept rebooting my system. So finally I killed cmd from task manager.

Comment: @hans I edited my answer. Is that how your code looks? Tell me if it works.